# Multiple goroutines listening on one channel

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have multiple goroutines trying to receive on the same channel simultaneously. It seems like the last goroutine that starts receiving on the channel gets the value. Is this somewhere in the language spec or is it undefined behaviour?

```
c := make(chan string)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        <-c
        c <- fmt.Sprintf("goroutine %d", i)
    }(i)
}
c <- "hi"
fmt.Println(<-c)
```

Output:

```
goroutine 4
```

[Example On Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7TuA7kLtks)

**EDIT:**

I just realized that it's more complicated than I thought. The message gets passed around all the goroutines.

```
c := make(chan string)
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        msg := <-c
        c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s, hi from %d", msg, i)
    }(i)
}
c <- "original"
fmt.Println(<-c)
```

Output:

```
original, hi from 0, hi from 1, hi from 2, hi from 3, hi from 4
```

**NOTE:** *the above output is outdated in more recent versions of Go (see comments)*

[Example On Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3y-YQG8dAb)

Comment: I tried your last snippet and (to my huge relief) it only outputted `original, hi from 4`...

Comment: @ChangQian adding a `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)` between the channel send and receive brings back the old behaviour.

Comment: @IliaCholy why does this happen? Anyone??

Comment: @IliaCholy no, the output can be varied whether or not we add `time.Sleep`. Also, IMO, it's not related to the version of Go.

Comment: @human I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71154776/10027592), please check it. The outputs can be different if you run the codes many times. Actually, the `time.Sleep` does *not* make the output fixed.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, it's complicated, But there are a couple of rules of thumb that should make things feel much more straightforward.

- **prefer using formal arguments for the channels** you pass to go-routines instead of accessing channels in global scope. You can get more compiler checking this way, and better modularity too.
- **avoid both reading and writing on the same channel in a particular go-routine** (including the 'main' one). Otherwise, deadlock is a much greater risk.

Here's an alternative version of your program, applying these two guidelines. This case demonstrates many writers & one reader on a channel:

```
c := make(chan string)

for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    go func(i int, co chan<- string) {
        for j := 1; j <= 5; j++ {
            co <- fmt.Sprintf("hi from %d.%d", i, j)
        }
    }(i, c)
}

for i := 1; i <= 25; i++ {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/quQn7xePLw

It creates the five go-routines writing to a single channel, each one writing five times. The main go-routine reads all twenty five messages - you may notice that the order they appear in is often not sequential (i.e. the concurrency is evident).

This example demonstrates a feature of Go channels: it is possible to have multiple writers sharing one channel; Go will interleave the messages automatically.

The same applies for one writer and multiple readers on one channel, as seen in the second example here:

```
c := make(chan int)
var w sync.WaitGroup
w.Add(5)

for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    go func(i int, ci <-chan int) {
        j := 1
        for v := range ci {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            fmt.Printf("%d.%d got %d\n", i, j, v)
            j += 1
        }
        w.Done()
    }(i, c)
}

for i := 1; i <= 25; i++ {
    c <- i
}
close(c)
w.Wait()
```

This [second example](http://play.golang.org/p/ESq9he_WzS) includes a wait imposed on the main goroutine, which would otherwise exit promptly and cause the other five goroutines to be terminated early *(thanks to [olov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001457/olov) for this correction)*.

In both examples, no buffering was needed. It is generally a good principle to view buffering as a performance enhancer only. If your program does not deadlock *without* buffers, it won't deadlock *with* buffers either (but the converse *is not* always true). So, as **another rule of thumb, start without buffering then add it later as needed**.

Comment: don't you need to wait for all goroutines to finish?

Comment: It depends what you mean. Have a look at the play.golang.org examples; they have a `main` function that terminates once it reaches the end, regardless of what any other goroutines are doing. In the first example above, `main` is lock-step with the other goroutines so there's no problem. The second example also works without problem because all messages are sent via `c` *before* the `close` function is called and this happens *before* the `main` goroutine terminates. (You might argue that calling `close` is superfluous in the case, but it's good practice.)

Comment: assuming that you want to (deterministically) see 15 printouts in the last example, you do need to wait. To demonstrate that, here's the same example but with a time.Sleep just before the Printf: http://play.golang.org/p/cEP-UBPLv6

Comment: And here's the same example with a time.Sleep and fixed with a WaitGroup to wait for the goroutines: http://play.golang.org/p/ESq9he_WzS

Comment: I don't think that's a good recommendation to omit buffering at first. Without buffering you actually don't write concurrent code, and that leads not only to that you can't deadlock, but also to that the handling result from the other side of the channel is already available on the next instruction after the sending, and you may unintentionally (or event intentionally in case of a novice) rely on that. And once you rely on the fact that you have a result immediately, without specially waiting for it, and you add a buffer, you have a race condition.

Comment: And a race condition is harder to debug than a deadlock because Go compiler detects deadlocks and tries to help you with a list of stuck goroutines, but it can't do anything with race conditions. In other words, leaving out buffering at start doesn't lead to a more thread-safe application architecture.

Comment: No, this is a misunderstanding of the point. If you learn to think of goroutines in an abstract CSP way, you'd envisage something akin to a data-flow graph diagram. The nodes in the graph represent the concurrent goroutines. With this model, you would share *nothing*, so there would be no race conditions (and the race detector should confirm this). Then you'd be left with the issue of deadlocks to deal with. At this point, it is easier to minimise or eliminate buffering in the conceptual model until the deadlocks have been understood and designed out.

Comment: Then re-add buffering where it gives better performance overall.

Comment: In simple code like that shown above, note that unbuffered channels between goroutines force the goroutines to interleave. They *are still running concurrently* but not necessarily in parallel. ([Concurrency is not parallelism](http://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism), Rob Pike)

Answer (score 41):

Late reply, but I hope this helps others in the future like [Long Polling, "Global" Button, Broadcast to everyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19802037/143225)

[Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) explains the issue:

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive.

That means that you cannot have more than 1 goroutine listening to 1 channel and expect ALL goroutines to receive the same value.

**Run this [Code Example](http://play.golang.org/p/NQGO5-jCVz).**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
        for v := range c {
                fmt.Printf("count %d from goroutine #%d\n", v, i)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 25; i++ {
        c<-i
    }

    close(c)
}
```

You will not see "count 1" more than once even though there are 5 goroutines listening to the channel. This is because when the first goroutine blocks the channel all other goroutines must wait in line. When the channel is unblocked, the count has already been received and removed from the channel so the next goroutine in line gets the next count value.

Comment: Thanks - now this example makes sense https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter6/listing20/listing20.go

Comment: Ahh this was helpful. Would a good alternative be to create a channel for each Go routine that needs the info, then send message on all channels when necessary? That's the option I can imagine.

Comment: 1) *"...goroutines must wait in line."*: Is there any reference? I'm just curious if one goroutine is selected randomly **or** they wait in line (both situations sound similar but slightly different). 2) we should add `sync.WaitGroup` if we wanna see all 25 outputs. Without it, the main goroutine will finish earlier.

Answer (score 9):

I've studied existing solutions and created simple broadcast library https://github.com/grafov/bcast.

```
    group := bcast.NewGroup() // you created the broadcast group
    go bcast.Broadcasting(0) // the group accepts messages and broadcast it to all members

    member := group.Join() // then you join member(s) from other goroutine(s)
    member.Send("test message") // or send messages of any type to the group 

    member1 := group.Join() // then you join member(s) from other goroutine(s)
    val := member1.Recv() // and for example listen for messages
```

Comment: Great lib you have there! I have found also https://github.com/asaskevich/EventBus

Comment: And not a big deal, but perhaps you should mention how to unjoin in the readme.

Comment: Memory leak there

Comment: :( Can you explain details @jhvaras?

Answer (score 8):

It is complicated.

Also, see what happens with `GOMAXPROCS = NumCPU+1`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU() + 1)
    fmt.Print(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))
    c := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            msg := <-c
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s, hi from %d", msg, i)
        }(i)
    }
    c <- ", original"
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Output:

```
5, original, hi from 4
```

And, see what happens with buffered channels. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 5+1)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            msg := <-c
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s, hi from %d", msg, i)
        }(i)
    }
    c <- "original"
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Output:

```
original
```

You should be able to explain these cases too.

Answer (score 3):

For multiple goroutine listen on one channel, yes, it's possible. the key point is the message itself, you can define some message like that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type obj struct {
    msg string
    receiver int
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan *obj) // both block or non-block are ok
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    receiver := 25 // specify receiver count

    sender := func() {
        o := &obj {
            msg: "hello everyone!",
            receiver: receiver,
        }
        ch <- o
    }
    recv := func(idx int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        o := <-ch
        fmt.Printf("%d received at %d\n", idx, o.receiver)
        o.receiver--
        if o.receiver > 0 {
            ch <- o // forward to others
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("last receiver: %d\n", idx)
        }
    }

    go sender()
    for i:=0; i<reciever; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go recv(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

The output is random:

```
5 received at 25
24 received at 24
6 received at 23
7 received at 22
8 received at 21
9 received at 20
10 received at 19
11 received at 18
12 received at 17
13 received at 16
14 received at 15
15 received at 14
16 received at 13
17 received at 12
18 received at 11
19 received at 10
20 received at 9
21 received at 8
22 received at 7
23 received at 6
2 received at 5
0 received at 4
1 received at 3
3 received at 2
4 received at 1
last receiver 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old question, but nobody mentioned this, I think.

First, the outputs of both examples **can be different** if you run the codes many times. This is not related to the Go version.

The output of the 1st example can be `goroutine 4`, `goroutine 0`, `goroutine 1`,... actually **all** the goroutine can be a one who sends the string to the main goroutine.

Main goroutine is one of the goroutines, so it's also waiting for data from the channel.
Which goroutine should receive the data? **Nobody knows.** It's not in the language spec.

Also, the output of the 2nd example also can be anything:

(I added the square brackets just for clarity)

```
// [original, hi from 4]
// [[[[[original, hi from 4], hi from 0], hi from 2], hi from 1], hi from 3]
// [[[[[original, hi from 4], hi from 1], hi from 0], hi from 2], hi from 3]
// [[[[[original, hi from 0], hi from 2], hi from 1], hi from 3], hi from 4]
// [[original, hi from 4], hi from 1]
// [[original, hi from 0], hi from 4]
// [[[original, hi from 4], hi from 1], hi from 0]
// [[[[[original, hi from 4], hi from 1], hi from 0], hi from 3], hi from 2]
// [[[[original, hi from 0], hi from 2], hi from 1], hi from 3]
//
// ......anything can be the output.
```

This is not magic, nor a mysterious phenomenon.

If there are multiple threads being executed, no one knows exactly which thread will acquire the resource. The language doesn't determine it. Rather, **OS takes care of it.** This is why multithread programming is quite complicated.

Goroutine is not OS thread, but it behaves somewhat similarly.

Comment: yes, it is random. I dont understand all the fuzz on this question....

Comment: @mh-cbon I posted this answer because the original question hasn't been answered yet (the question was: *"Is this somewhere in the language spec or is it undefined behaviour?"*). OP even misunderstood his/her code examples, but no one told about it.

Comment: Note that with computers having more and more CPUs, it is likely that 5 goroutines will be exactly 5 threads. At the same time, the wait on a channel must not block a thread since that thread could be used by another awake goroutine instead.

Comment: And strangely enough you are the only one who mentions the fact that the threads are non-deterministic and thus to my point of view, your answer is the most valid one at the moment.

Comment: coming back years later, you're the only one who made the point, brackets are really helpful for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sync.Cond` is a good choice.

ref: https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Cond

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).