# Go: one channel with multiple listeners

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to Go so sorry if the topic is wrong but I hope you understand my question. I want to process events to different go routines via a channel. Here is some sample code

```
type Event struct {
    Host string
    Command string
    Output string
}


var (
    incoming        = make(chan Event)
)

func processEmail(ticker* time.Ticker) {
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Email Tick at", t)
        case e := <-incoming:
            fmt.Println("EMAIL GOT AN EVENT!")
            fmt.Println(e)
        }
    }
}

func processPagerDuty(ticker* time.Ticker) {
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Pagerduty Tick at", t)
        case e := <-incoming:
            fmt.Println("PAGERDUTY GOT AN EVENT!")
            fmt.Println(e)
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(&cfg, "dispatch-api.cfg")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error loading the config")
    }

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 10)
    go processEmail(ticker)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 1)
    go processPagerDuty(ticker)
}


func eventAdd(r render.Render, params martini.Params, req *http.Request) {

    // create an event now
    e := Event{Host: "web01-east.domain.com", Command: "foo", Output: "bar"}
    incoming <- e
}
```

So the ticker events work just create. When I issue an API call to create an event I just get output from the processEmail function. Its whatever go routine is called first will get the event over the channel.

Is there a way for both functions to get that event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple goroutines listening on one channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715605/multiple-goroutines-listening-on-one-channel)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use *fan in* and *fan out* (from Rob Pike's speech):

```
package main

func main() {
    // feeders - feeder1, feeder2 and feeder3 are used to fan in
    // data into one channel
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case v1 := <-feeder1:
                mainChannel <- v1
            case v2 := <-feeder2:
                mainChannel <- v2
            case v3 := <-feeder3:
                mainChannel <- v3
            }
        }
    }()

    // dispatchers - not actually fan out rather dispatching data
    go func() {
        for {
            v := <-mainChannel

            // use this to prevent leaking goroutines
            // (i.e. when one consumer got stuck)
            done := make(chan bool)

            go func() {
                consumer1 <- v
                done <- true
            }()
            go func() {
                consumer2 <- v
                done <- true
            }()
            go func() {
                consumer3 <- v
                done <- true
            }()

            <-done
            <-done
            <-done
        }
    }()

    // or fan out (when processing the data by just one consumer is enough)
    go func() {
        for {
            v := <-mainChannel
            select {
            case consumer1 <- v:
            case consumer2 <- v:
            case consumer3 <- v:
            }
        }
    }()

    // consumers(your logic)
    go func() { <-consumer1 /* using the value */ }()
    go func() { <-consumer2 /* using the value */ }()
    go func() { <-consumer3 /* using the value */ }()
}

type payload int

var (
    feeder1 = make(chan payload)
    feeder2 = make(chan payload)
    feeder3 = make(chan payload)

    mainChannel = make(chan payload)

    consumer1 = make(chan payload)
    consumer2 = make(chan payload)
    consumer3 = make(chan payload)
)
```

Comment: thanks.. i went with this solution and it should do what I need it to do.

Comment: What happens when a consumer gets stuck. Doesn't that also get the dispather stuck as it won't get the third done? Isn't that behaviour equivalent to above code without the done channel?

Comment: True and a `sync.WaitGroup` would have the same problem. Now there is a need for introducing timeouts to identify unresponsive consumers and ... I would say at that point a more robust solution like NATS might be a more proper choice! :)

Answer (score 9):

Channels are a point to point communication method, not a broadcast communication method, so no, you can't get both functions to get the event without doing something special.

You could have separate channels for both goroutines and send the message into each.  This is probably the simplest solution.

Or alternatively you could get one goroutine to signal the next one.

Go has two mechanisms for doing broadcast signalling as far as I know.  One is closing a channel.  This only works a single time though.

The other is to use a [sync.Cond](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond) lock. These are moderately tricky to use, but will allow you to have multiple goroutines woken up by a single event.

If I was you, I'd go for the first option, send the event to two different channels.  That seems to map the problem quite well.

Comment: Strictly speaking, closing a channel is a multicast signal rather than a broadcast. Only those goroutines that are attempting to use the channel are notified.