# Why declaring a channel in global scope gives deadlock issue

Tags: go, concurrency, scope, deadlock, channel

Out of 3 code snippets, the one with channels declared in local scope works, other code snippets gives deadlock issue, One of the previously [answered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721380/5221796) here says try to avoid declaring channel in the global scope. I checked in the [official docs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#channels), but I didn't find any explanation.

1. Why is the global scope channel giving an error although I am not blocking the channel from sending and receiving? why am I getting a deadlock issue here?
2. How is `make(chan int)` different from `var myChan chan int` except in terms of scope and initialization?
3. Can anyone explain and suggest better articles/documents/links/pdfs to effectively use channels(and implement concurrency) in Go?

(imports and 'package main' is omitted from snippets for purpose of brevity)

```
// 1. channel declared in global scope
var c chan int
func main(){
    go send()
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
func send(){
    c <- 42
}
//output: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

// 2. channel declared in global scope + sending channel to goroutine
var c chan int
func main(){
    go send(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
func send(c chan int){
    c <- 42
}
//output: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

// 3. using channel as local scope and sharing it with goroutine
func main(){
    c := make(chan int)
    go send(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
func send(c chan int){
    c <- 42
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because by declaring an uninitialized `var c chan int`, `c` has its type's zero value, which in case of a `chan` is `nil`.

If you actually [run your code](https://play.golang.org/p/12fDlIdP6Tu), the error message reveals this information. Both goroutines are sending/receiving on a `nil` chan:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive (nil chan)]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox288806111/prog.go:11 +0x5c

goroutine 18 [chan send (nil chan)]:
main.send()
    /tmp/sandbox288806111/prog.go:15 +0x39
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox288806111/prog.go:10 +0x39
```

With `make` instead you are explicitly initializing the variable `c`, which is then not `nil`.

This has nothing to do with the global scope per-se. In fact if you properly initialize the variable, e.g. `var c chan int = make(chan int)`, even in the global scope, the program won't deadlock.

---

Additional readings: [channel axioms (Dave Cheney)](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms)

> If the channel is nil then the sender and receiver have no reference to each other; they are both blocked waiting on independent channels and will never unblock.