# exiting multiple go routines waiting on an unbuffered channel

Tags: go

I was trying to exit multiple Goroutines Simultaneously.
According to https://www.godesignpatterns.com/2014/04/exiting-multiple-goroutines-simultaneously.html
there is a well defined way to do it.

Another approach i see is the following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var inCh chan int = make(chan int, 100)
    var exit chan bool = make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go func(instance int) {
            fmt.Println("In go routine ", instance)
            for {
                select {
                case <-exit:
                    fmt.Println("Exit received from ", instance)
                    exit <- true
                    return
                case value := <-inCh:
                    fmt.Println("Value=", value)
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    exit <- true
    <-exit   // Final exit
    fmt.Println("Final exit")
}
```

But I am confused and i really don't get it why the unbuffered channel at the end is executed as a last statement.
In reality I have 20 go routines listening for exit channel. Randomly one will receive it and send it to another.
Why always the reception within go routines is taking place and only when all of them are finished the channel reception with comment "// Final Exit" will execute ?

I will really appreciate if someone can give me an explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd choose this over just closing the channel, which is the standard way of broadcasting a signal to many listeners. What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: I have chosen the first solution with just closing the channel. But I also found somewhere this approach and i don;t really figure out why it is working !

Comment: But why the " exit <- true" within the go routine is not enabling the "final" exit but it enables only the go routines started from the main function to receive it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this slight modification.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var exit chan int = make(chan int)
        var workers = 20
    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go func(instance int) {
            fmt.Println("In go routine ", instance)
            for {
                select {
                case i := <-exit:
                    fmt.Println("Exit", i, "received from ", instance)
                    exit <- i-1
                    return
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }
    exit <- workers
    fmt.Println("Final exit:", <-exit)
}
```

Here, I've done 3 things: First, I removed the unused channel, for brevity.  Second, I removed the sleep.  third, I changed the `exit` channel to an `int` channel that is decremented by every pass.  If I pass the number of workers in, any value other than `0` from the "Final" message indicates dropped workers.

Here's one example run:

```
% go run t.go
In go routine  8
In go routine  5
In go routine  0
In go routine  2
Exit 20 received from  8
Exit 19 received from  5
Final exit: 18
In go routine  13
```

When `main` calls `time.Sleep` it doesn't get scheduled until the sleep is over.  The other goroutines all have this time to set up their channel readers.  I can only assume, because I can't find it written anywhere, that channel readers are likely to be queued in roughly chronological error - thus, the `sleep` guarantees that `main`'s reader is the last.

If this is consistent behavior, it certainly isn't *reliable*.

See [Multiple goroutines listening on one channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715605/multiple-goroutines-listening-on-one-channel) for many more thoughts on this.

Comment: That's my issue...i cannot find it in the spec..."channel readers are queued..."

Comment: Probably because it's not in the spec.  The success of this code is merely incidental.  It's out of spec.

Answer (score 2):

Use `close()` for cancelation as shown in the linked article.

The code in question is not guaranteed to work. Here's a scenario where it fails:

1. One goroutine is ready to receive from `exit`. All other goroutines busy somewhere else.
2. The value sent by main is received by the ready goroutine.
3. That goroutine sends a value to `exit` that is received by `main()`.

The other goroutines do not exit because no more values are sent to `exit`.  See [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/cUQ4UIXzCBz) that uses time.Seep to induce the problem scenario.

> Why always the reception within go routines is taking place and only when all of them are finished the channel reception with comment "// Final Exit" will execute ?

The program executes as if the channel maintains an ordered queue of waiting goroutines, but there's nothing in the specification that guarantees that behavior. Even if the channel has an ordered queue, the program can encounter the scenario above if a goroutine is doing something other than waiting on receive from `exit`.

Comment: "...executes as if the channel maintains an ordered queue of waiting goroutines..." I am not counting on this as I don't consider the example I posted as a proposed solution over the "close channel" approach. I was just wondering why it is always working and it seems that indeed this might be the approach of the compiler but wanted to see others view.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the output of you program

```
In go routine  6
In go routine  0
In go routine  7
.
.
Exit received from  6
Exit received from  0
Exit received from  7
.
.
Final exit
```

They get called in the same( or almost the same) order of how they were started. If none of your Go routines are busy the first one registered will be used. This is just an implementation of the runtime and I would not count on this behavior.

Your final exit was the last channel to be listened on so it is used last.

If you remove the time.Sleep after your loop your final exit will get called almost immediately and most of your go routines will not receive the exit signal

Output with out time.Sleep (will very between runs)

```
In go routine  0
Exit received from  0
In go routine  1
In go routine  2
In go routine  3
In go routine  4
In go routine  5
In go routine  6
In go routine  7
In go routine  14
In go routine  15
In go routine  16
In go routine  17
In go routine  18
In go routine  19
Final exit
```

Comment: Your comment "...Your final exit was the last channel to be listened on so it is used last...." seems to be the only logic explanation of what I am asking...BUT is there such an order specified somewhere ? I only know about "...Channels act as first-in-first-out queues..."

Comment: @MakisPapapanagiotou no this is not in the spec. This is kind of like how maps used to be kind of sorted and then the compiler introduced forced randomization so programers would not rely on the undefined behavior.  Your program only appears to work because your go routines are not actually doing any work and are all just blocking in the select statement.

Comment: Ok, in reality the code example is just over simplified just for convenience purposes, but in any case it seems that indeed it is working independent of any sleep  or channel busy scenarios just because of the fact the "last" exit channel in put as last in the queue. Of courser I am cannot find it in any spec but seems the only reasonable explanation. So I will consider it as a correct answer. Thanx !!!